# C# Forms value retention

Tags: c#, winforms

I am hiding one form and then going to different forms, but i am trying to use the value of a variable calculated on first form. Is it true that when I am on, suppose, 4th form,  i cannot use those values on form1 as they become zero. As my function always generates a zero using those values
Can you please tell me what could possibly go wrong?
If this doesent seem to be the problem I can then explain in more detail my code an problem
thank you

Comment: When you store the values are you storing them directly in the form actions or you use some sort of the objects.

Comment: Why should not store your 1st form value in `Session`.IS there any problem if yes than clear your question.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the Form class instead of using the existing one.  If you programmed in Visual Basic before then you might find Application.OpenForms handy.

Comment: I am using c sharp and visual studio, then how do i use the existing form rather than the new instance?

Answer (score 4):

Since `Form` is a class, the forms you are showing are instances of that class, and thus, the data is really local to that form.  If you are showing a new instance, then yes the original data is gone.

The idea is use public methods or properties to get data from those forms.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();

    public string TBData
    {
        get { return t.Text; }
    }
}

// outside:
Form f = new MyForm();
f.Show()

//f.TBData will get what is in the text box.
```

Comment: the forms that I created are public and i am trying to use a value created on first form on the third form, but it doesent work

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal Do you have the reference of the first form being passed on to the others, in that case you should be able to access the values via public properties

Comment: I created appropriate objects of respective forms to call its variables

Comment: It has nothing to do with the form being public. You have to have a reference to the form, and then access its public members (in this case properties)

Comment: I got it fixed, the orignal answer was the key, I was creating a new instance of the form for the function and hence the data was gone. I refered to the orignal instance and it worked!!

Comment: Great to hear! Remember to accept an answer if it helped solved your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow!